# When does the second Captain Marvel post-credits scene take place?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

In the second post-credit scene of *Captain Marvel*, we see

> Goose throwing up the Tesseract on Fury's desk

When does this happen in the MARVEL timeline? (Some time before *The Avengers*, I believe?)

Comment: This was the first question my wife asked as we were walking from the theater to the car after seeing it last night.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In 1995. Just because Fury isn’t in the office, you can’t assume it’s post-snap (that would just be wrong).

- There's a CRT monitor on the desk.
- Behind the desk, there's an [Aeron chair](https://www.hermanmiller.com/products/seating/office-chairs/aeron-chairs/), which is contemporary to that time period.

It’s generally assumed that this event has to take place so that the Tesseract can be used for experimentation.

[Further reading on the Tesseract timeline](https://screenrant.com/tesseract-captain-marvel-mcu-timeline-plot-hole/).

Comment: He had a CRT monitor on his desk, so definitely in the 1990s.

Comment: Did they have those high-end web-back chairs in the 90s? He had one of those as well.

Comment: @VBartilucci: [they did](http://nymag.com/news/intelligencer/21364/). Lots of tech startups bought them in the 90s, then sold them when the dot-com bubble burst, meaning you probably would have only started seeing them everywhere in the 00s.

Comment: @MichaelStern People were still commonly using CRTs in the early 2000s. https://productplacementblog.com/movies/lays-chips-and-dell-monitor-the-terminal-2004/ , https://productplacementblog.com/movies/viewsonic-monitor-in-spider-man-2-2004/ (For some purposes, people kept using CRTs for quite a while. Until at least the end of the '00s, flat panel displays didn't quite catch up on color reproduction and response time.)